# How do we calculate the correct p-values in a linear regression model when we know the coefficients are always positive?

Tags: regression

Suppose, we use least-squares regression and obtain a coefficient. Suppose, we know that the coefficient can never be negative.

Then instead of testing the relationship:

$$\mathrm{H}_0 : \beta_1 = 0$$
$$\mathrm{H}_a : \beta_1 \ne 0$$

we can test:

$$\mathrm{H}_0 : \beta_1 = 0$$
$$\mathrm{H}_a : \beta_1 > 0$$

For example, if we have a normalized sample $t = 3.3$ our p-value with a coefficient that can be negative or positive it would be:

$$ p = \Pr(t > 3.3 \vee t < -3.3) = 2\Pr(t > 3.3)$$

but if our coefficient can only be negative or positive it would be:

$$ p = \Pr(t > 3.3)$$

So, if the coefficient can be negative we have to have a p-value that is twice as high right?

I'm also not sure how this applies to the F test.

Traditionally, the F test is:

$$ \mathrm{H}_0 :  \beta_1 - \beta_2 = 0 $$
$$ \mathrm{H}_a : \beta_1 - \beta_2 \ne 0 $$

but generalized to more than 2 variables.

However, if we have only positive coefficients we can use a ratio test and can divide our possibilities by half.

$$ \mathrm{H}_0 :  \beta_1 / \beta_2 = 1 $$
$$ \mathrm{H}_a : \beta_1 / \beta_2 > 1 \vee (0 < \beta_1 / \beta_2 < 1) $$

How do we calculate the correct p-values in a linear regression model when we know the coefficients are always positive?